# displaying multiple arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

these are my arrays

```
var CarType=["RM","BM","GM"];
var CarName=["Red Mustang","Black Mustang","Green Mustang"]
```

how would I create a simple function that when a button is pushed an alert would pop up that displays something like this:

RM = Red Mustang

BM = Black Mustang

GM = Green Mustang

Comment: You could use a simple `for` loop to iterate over both arrays at once and concatenate the values to build up your message. Which part are you stuck on? (Also, I would store that data as a single array of objects: `[{type:"RM", name: "Red Mustang"}, {type:"BM", name: "Black Mustang"}, ...]`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function myFunction() {
   var CarType=["RM","BM","GM"];
   var CarName=["Red Mustang","Black Mustang","Green Mustang"];
   var result = "";
   for(var i in CarType){
     result += [CarType[i] + " = " + CarName[i]] + "\n";
    }
   alert(result)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks so much this worked. Just so I can understand, what does the 'n' in "/n" do?

Comment: You're welcome!. The "\n" is just going to add a new line, that is all. Please mark my answer as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark and it will turn green. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should go something like this.

*Your arrays must have same size for this to work and sorted*

```
function display(carType, carName) {

     var text = "";

     for (i=0; i < carType.length; i++) {
         text += carType[i] + " = " + carName[i] + "\n";
     }

     alert(text);
}

var CarType=["RM","BM","GM"];
var CarName=["Red Mustang","Black Mustang","Green Mustang"];

display(CarType, CarName);
```